# Does any 4.3+ device with Bluetooth v4.0 support iBeacon (BLE) scanning?

Tags: bluetooth

### Facts

1. Bluetooth Low Energy is part of the Bluetooth v4.0 Specification.
2. Android v4.3+ implements support for BLE Scanning

### Question

Does this imply that any device that satisfies the above mentioned points actually mean that the device in practice will allow BLE scanning?

Or this should be stated specifically by the provider itself?

### Background story:

I am looking for the cheapest android device to develop an iBeacon app for. It has to function only on that specific device.

I've been looking at the [Wiko Sunset 2](http://www.gsmarena.com/wiko_sunset2-7457.php) which satisfies the two rules, but I haven't found anywhere information about it if it would support BLE Scanning or not.

Comment: Since you are specifically interested in that device, wouldn't mailing OEM get you the answer, since with low end phones, specifications don't go into detail

Comment: Did that as well, but I thought an open question / answer would also help someone searching the answer to the generic question.

Comment: I searched but didn't get any specific answer